# Pygame - TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not list when flipping an image

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4

```
boss.ani = glob.glob("Mobs\Mob_2\stand_*.png")
boss.img = pygame.transform.flip(boss.ani,True,False)
```

I'm trying to take 5 images, boss.ani, and flip them so they face the opposite direction, this is what's wrong and I get this error:

```
  line 54, in __init__
    boss.img = pygame.transform.flip(boss.ani,True,False)
TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not list
```

What would I have to do to flip the whole list of images?

Comment: And what do you expect us to do? You're passing a list (e.g. `['a', 'b', 'c']`) to the flip function, and it doesn't like it. Have you considered trying to understand the traceback? They're incredible simple and friendly, and they definitely don't bite.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that glob.glob creates a list of pygame.Surface objects using pygame.image.load().

If this is in fact the case, your issue is that your calling the whole list instead of each object. To fix this, all you need to do is loop through the bos.ani list like so:

```
boss.img = [] # Creates the object to hold the transformed images
for image in boss.ani: # Loop through the boss.ani list
    boss.img.append(pygame.transform.flip(image,True,False)) # Append each transformed image to the boss.img list
```

Hopefully this helps. :)